# GmailAPI service account user rate limited but not according to console graphs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gmail-api

We are hitting "User-rate limit exceeded" but all the quota graphs are well under the limits unless I'm interpreting them wrong.

I'm aware of the user limit of 250 units per second.
There's also a per 100 seconds limit of 25,000 per user
and 2,000,000 units per 100 seconds across all users.

We are making a request every 20 seconds from a runner that connects to the GmailAPI and lists messages retrieves messages.

There are never more than a few messages in the inbox at a time.

According queries per 100 seconds graph there's 625 units
I really don't know where it's getting the 250 per second from.
Some of the other graphs are even more confusing.

```
ids =
  @gmail.fetch_all(max: 100, items: :messages) do |token|
    @gmail.list_user_messages('me', max_results: 100, q: query, page_token: token)
  end.map(&:id)

puts "Processing #{ids.count} emails for #{watcher[:id]}"

on_complete = lambda do |result, err|
  retrieve_complete(result, err, watcher)
end

ids.each_slice(1000) do |ids_array|
  @gmail.batch do |gm|
    ids_array.each { |id| gm.get_user_message('me', id, &on_complete) }
  end
end
```

[image]
[image]
[image]